# Progress bar with Vue and Axios

Tags: progress-bar, vuejs2, progress, axios

I'm making an image uploader, and I'd like to display a progress bar which starts incrementing once a file is selected.

I'm using Axios to access the backend, and have it setup like this:

```
const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:3000';

function uploadImage(data, listingId) {
  const url = `${BASE_URL}/listings/${listingId}/images`;
  let config = {
    onUploadProgress(progressEvent) {
      var percentCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) /
        progressEvent.total);
      return percentCompleted;
    },
  };
  return axios.post(url, data, config).
      then(x => x.request.response).
      catch(error => error);
}
```

How can I access the `percentCompleted` from the Vue side below?

```
inputDidChange(e) {
  let inputData = e.target.files[0];
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('image', inputData);
  uploadImage(formData, this.listingId).
    then((x) => {
      var xParsed = JSON.parse(x);
      this.newFile = xParsed.image.image.url;
      this.files.push(this.newFile);
      console.log('success');
  });
},
```

Comment: Is `inputDidChange` a Vue method?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pass a callback to your `uploadImage` function.

```
function uploadImage(data, listingId, onProgress){
  const url = `${BASE_URL}/listings/${listingId}/images`;
  let config = {
     onUploadProgress(progressEvent) {
      var percentCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) /
        progressEvent.total);

      // execute the callback
      if (onProgress) onProgress(percentCompleted)

      return percentCompleted;
    },
  };
  return axios.post(url, data, config).
      then(x => x.request.response).
      catch(error => error);
}
```

And then pass in a Vue method.

```
methods:{
  onProgress(percent){
    //update vue
  },
  inputDidChange(e) {
    let inputData = e.target.files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', inputData);
    uploadImage(formData, this.listingId, this.onProgress).
      then((x) => {
        var xParsed = JSON.parse(x);
        this.newFile = xParsed.image.image.url;
        this.files.push(this.newFile);
        console.log('success');
    });
  },
}
```